# NullPointerException on a getter from a many-to-one relationship on realm

Tags: java, android, realm, relationship, one-to-many

I'm creating a note-taking app with each note having a list of tasks in them. I'm using realm to create a one-to-many relationship on each note for its respective tasks. Everytime I try to add a task to the note, it gives me a null pointer exception with the error pointing here:

```
note.getTaskItems().add(t);
```

Here is the whole code for the activity including the code above:

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskAdapter.IconClick {
RecyclerView recview;
TaskAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<TaskItem> listData;
Realm trealm;
EditText edtTask;
TaskItem taskItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TaskMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.task_main);

    trealm.getDefaultInstance();

    //RecyclerView
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.task_rec);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    //Realm
    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

    //TaskRealmHelper helper = new TaskRealmHelper(trealm);
    listData = retrieve();

    adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, listData);
    recview.setAdapter(adapter);



    binding.fbtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayInputDialog();
        }
    });
}

private void displayInputDialog() {
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("save to realm");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box);

    edtTask = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtTask);
    Button btn1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get
                //TaskItem t = new TaskItem();
                //t.setTasks(edtTask.getText().toString());
            //save
            save(edtTask.getText().toString());
            edtTask.setText("");
            //refresh
            //listData = retrieve();
            adapter = new TaskAdapter(TaskActivity.this, listData);
            recview.setAdapter(adapter);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    d.show();
}

public void save(final String input) {
    trealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    trealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            //taskItem = realm.createObject(TaskItem.class,UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            TaskItem t = new TaskItem();
            t.setTaskid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            t.setTasks(input);
            //t = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(t);
            NoteItem note = trealm.where(NoteItem.class)
                    .equalTo("Noteid", getIntent().getExtras().getString("taskid"))
                    .findFirst();
            listData.add(t);
            note.getTaskItems().add(t);
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<TaskItem> retrieve()
{
    trealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    ArrayList<TaskItem> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    RealmQuery<NoteItem> q = trealm.where(NoteItem.class);
    if(tasks.size()>0)
    {
        q = q.equalTo("id", getIntent().getExtras().getString("taskid"));
    }

    RealmResults<TaskItem> item = trealm.where(TaskItem.class)
            //.equalTo("taskid","id")
            .findAllAsync();

    for (TaskItem t : item)
    {
        tasks.add(t);
        //note.getTaskItems().add(t);
    }
    return tasks;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmList com.example.ffuf_m.intern_project_w_architecture.data.models.items.NoteItem.getTaskItems()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ffuf_m.intern_project_w_architecture.ui.activities.TaskActivity$3.execute(TaskActivity.java:121)
    at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1444)
    at com.example.ffuf_m.intern_project_w_architecture.ui.activities.TaskActivity.save(TaskActivity.java:109)
    at com.example.ffuf_m.intern_project_w_architecture.ui.activities.TaskActivity$2.onClick(TaskActivity.java:95)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace too.

Comment: added the stack trace

Comment: It means the reference var **note** is null. It's not getting initialized from the method chain calling.

Comment: It says `note` is null, meaning there is no `Note` where `.equalTo("Noteid", getIntent().getExtras().getString("taskid"))` is true

Comment: so what you're saying is the note isn't getting any match from the intent?

Comment: Yes, for some reason your note wasn't found.